# Neo4j using long as Id

Tags: neo4j

I am using long ids indexing Nodes.
Why when I request ids 882573709873217600, 882573709873217509 and some other variants Neo4j returns Node with 882573709873217500 id?
I tried from Java to get the ID of this Node and it is 882573709873217536.
I tried to insert in my DB via my Java application a new Node with id 882751175233294337 and I get a Node in Neo4j with ID 882751175233294300. It is not just a problem with UI like I saw in an other question, when I request in my app ID 882751175233294300 I get this new Node!
Many thanks!!!!

Comment: It is a problem with how javascript handles longs (aka the browser etc). This question has been posted millions of times. Check https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver#read-integers

Comment: I don't use Javascript and this question has not been posted millions of times.

Comment: You can't declare the internal Neo4j id of a node or relationship, it's read-only and out of your hands. You can however create your own separate property and add an index on that. Also, it's hard to troubleshoot this without example code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Moving my answer to a comment, as it wasn't really an "answer": I can confirm a problem with the Neo4j browser in Neo4j versions 3.2.1 and 3.2.2 regarding display of some long values according to your observations: `RETURN 882573709873217509` should demonstrate the issue. Not reproducible in 3.2.0, 3.1.5, and presumably versions prior.

Next step is to figure out if this is a browser issue or a driver issue. Did you encounter this with the browser, or the Java bolt driver? If the driver, then what version of the driver are you using?

Comment: Also, please update your question and description, as it's not really a question at all right now. Please make it clear what this is asking for.

Comment: It is not internal ID, it is my "ID" property with long values.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to a [bug in the browser](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/618) affecting versions 3.2.1 and 3.2.2, resulting in bad long values being displayed when the high portion of a 64-bit long is non-zero.

As Neo4j only uses 64-bit values, this is an issue with few good workarounds.

If using 3.2.1, view results using the Text result view, as this is displaying the correct value.

Otherwise, avoid using the browser in 3.2.2 when viewing long values. Maybe try using `cypher-shell` instead.